# GetExtras not working

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to send Extras from Activity A to B.
The sending part is good, and the variables are not nulls, but I can't figure out how can I get them in Activity B.
This is the code of sending:

```
    public void sendToFavorites(Context context){
        String vID,vThumbnail,vTitle;
        vID = sendResult.getId().getVideoId();
        vThumbnail = sendResult.getSnippet().getThumbnails().getMedium().getUrl();
        vTitle = sendResult.getSnippet().getTitle();
        Intent fav = new Intent(context,Favorites.class);
        fav.putExtra("title",vTitle);
        fav.putExtra("thumbnail",vThumbnail);
        fav.putExtra("id",vID);
}
```

This is the code of getting:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.favorites_layout);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Favorites");
    initializeViews();
    //////////////////
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    vidID = extras.getString("id");
    vidTitle = extras.getString("title");
    vidThumbnail = extras.getString("thumbnail");
    loadFavorites();
}
```

Here I start Activity B:

```
    @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.favorites:
            intent = new Intent(this, Favorites.class);
            startActivity(intent);
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

for some reason, the application crashes when I'm launching Activity B with NO log..

What am I doing worng?

Comment: Are you calling `startActivity(fav)` to start `Activity B` somewhere?

Comment: @PPartisan no, Activity B starts in another place, I just want to send data.

Comment: could you please post the logcat too..

Comment: what do you mean by *Activity B starts in another place,*

Comment: @Lal I wish I could, the application crashes without log.

Comment: How about putting breakpoint and see where it crashes?

Comment: @Blackbelt I start Activity B by choosing it from Actionbar menu, not right after I send the data.

Comment: @Mithun I did, crashes as soon as I open Activity B without logcat..

Comment: Your logcat is empty? restart your IDE and try running the app..your logcat should say something..

Comment: are you filling up the intent you use to start the activity ?

Comment: @john-doe Nevermind - I'll type up an answer

Comment: You mean, it didn't even enter onCreate(...) of Activity B?

Comment: @Blackbelt I'm sending data, and when I start the Activity I want to use it. I t could be 5 minutes after I sent the data and it could be right after. I added the method to start Activity B.

Comment: @Mithun It won't even get to OnCreate.

Comment: *I'm sending data* doen't mean anything

Comment: @Blackbelt I'm doing the PutExtra, and then I choose from the Actionbar menu to start Activity B. Btw, If I put startActivity(fav) I get this error: android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread android.app.ActivityThread.getApplicationThread()' on a null object reference

Comment: can you update your question adding the *method* you are using to start ActivityB ?

Comment: @JohnDoe Take a look at my answer. You are declaring a new `Intent` object to start `Favourites.class`. Anything you place inside `fav` earlier will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void sendToFavorites(Context context){
        String vID,vThumbnail,vTitle;
        vID = sendResult.getId().getVideoId();
        vThumbnail = sendResult.getSnippet().getThumbnails().getMedium().getUrl();
        vTitle = sendResult.getSnippet().getTitle();
        Intent fav = new Intent(context,Favorites.class);
        fav.putExtra("title",vTitle);
        fav.putExtra("thumbnail",vThumbnail);
        fav.putExtra("id",vID);
    }
```

Your `Intent` object `fav` only applies to this method. As you never call `startActivity(fav)` in this method, then however you are starting `Activity B` will not include your bundled data. There are two possible alternatives - either declare `fav` as a class variable and reference it later, like so:

```
public class MyClass extends ... {

Intent fav;
//...
    public void sendToFavorites(Context context){
        String vID,vThumbnail,vTitle;
        vID = sendResult.getId().getVideoId();
        vThumbnail = sendResult.getSnippet().getThumbnails().getMedium().getUrl();
        vTitle = sendResult.getSnippet().getTitle();
        fav = new Intent(context,Favorites.class);
        fav.putExtra("title",vTitle);
        fav.putExtra("thumbnail",vThumbnail);
        fav.putExtra("id",vID);
    }

//...later, during a button click....
    if (fav != null) {
       startActivity(fav);
    }
```

Or, as I would prefer, place the logic from your `sendToFavourites()` method inside your click event:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.favorites:
            String vID,vThumbnail,vTitle;
            vID = sendResult.getId().getVideoId();
            vThumbnail = sendResult.getSnippet().getThumbnails().getMedium().getUrl();
            vTitle = sendResult.getSnippet().getTitle();
            Intent fav = new Intent(context, Favorites.class); //Could use "this" instead of context if this class extends Activity
            fav.putExtra("title",vTitle);
            fav.putExtra("thumbnail",vThumbnail);
            fav.putExtra("id",vID);
            startActivity(fav);
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try it and update. I liked the first idea more.

Comment: That's fine - it's just in the first instance you will have to account for situations where `fav` is null. Perhaps you can include the code in the second patch as part of an `if...else...` statement in case `fav` has not be instantiated.

Comment: I tried the first idea with no luck, It won't go into Favorites. I tried to add startActivity inside sendToFavorites but it crashes..

Comment: this is the error I get: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread android.app.ActivityThread.getApplicationThread()' on a null object reference

Comment: It would help if you copy-pasted your `LogCat` output into your OP, but first can I ask what you are using for your `context` parameter? If your class extends `Activity`, try using `this` instead of `context`. If it extends `Fragment`, use `getActivity()`.

Comment: @JohnDoe I can't think of what it could be then based on what you've posted, sorry. `Logcat` should give you the line where the error occurred - if you took a look at that and edited your OP to include that line and the full stack trace/error message then I could take a look, but I don't think there's enough to go on atm.

Comment: Okay, I will update the post tommarrow with more detail.